# asp.net mail add ReplyTo

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

How can i add a a different email then the sender in the `ReplayTo` field ?
Seems `MailMessage.ReplyTo` is deprecated so I'm trying to use `ReplyToList` instead.

But it's telling me that

```
Property or indexer 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.ReplyToList' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Here is my code so far:

```
var reply = new MailAddressCollection();
 reply.Add("test@test.com");
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderEmail,usr.Email,"subject","message");
 mail.ReplyToList = reply;
 var smtp = new SmtpClient();
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't *set* it to a whole new `MailAddressCollection`, but you can add directly to the existing `MailAddressCollection`, like this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderEmail,usr.Email,"subject","message");
mail.ReplyToList.Add("test@test.com");
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: for more check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436827/unable-to-add-reply-to-in-mail-header-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

Since the `ReplyToList` is a readonly property,the only way you can do is :

```
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("abc@xyz.com"));
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("def@abc.com"));
```