# Unable to add reply to in mail header C#

Tags: c#

I am developing Windows Form Application, Dot net Framework 4.  for sending SMTP emails.

I am using following code to send email.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("\"Company Name\" <info@company.com>", textBox_Email_to.Text);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "host name";

mail.Subject = "test email";
mail.Body = file; // file contains some text
mail.Headers.Add("reply-to", "service@company.de");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(mail);
```

The only problem is `mail.Headers.Add("reply-to", "service@company.de");` is not working.

I also tried to use `mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("service@company.de");`

But still its not working. While using `mail.ReplyTo` I am getting this warning:

'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.ReplyTo' is obsolete: '"ReplyTo is obsoleted for this type.  Please use ReplyToList instead which can accept multiple addresses.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Exception tells you what to do - use ReplyToList:

In your case it looks like this:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("\"Company Name\" <info@company.com>", textBox_Email_to.Text);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "host name";

        mail.Subject = "test email";
        mail.Body = file; // file contains some text

        //mail.Headers.Add("reply-to", "service@company.de");
        mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("service@company.de", "reply-to"));

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like it's giving you the advice to follow: use `ReplyToList` instead:

```
mail.ReplyToList.Add("service@company.de");
```

Comment: I tried but this is not working then I tired   mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("service@company.de"); and it worked out. Thanks anyways !!

Comment: Hmm, not working to me either, no emails is sending. I have to use email.To.Add("emailaddress"); and send separate emails without any reply.